# NEAT: How to properly handle Node IDs and avoid Competing Conventions?

Tags: neat, neuroevolution

I'm working on yet another NEAT implementation for a personal project, and I feel like I'm missing something about the proposed solution to the Competing Conventions problem.

Here's what I'm assuming:

- Each new *connection gene* yields a new innovation number.

> The new connection gene created in the first mutation is assigned the number 7, and the two new connection genes added during the new node mutation are assigned the numbers 8 and 9.

- If a connection from `X` to `Y` appears more than once **at the same generation**, it receives the same innovation number.

> However,  by  keeping  a  list  of  the  innovations  that  occurred  *in  the  current  generation*,  it is possible to ensure that when the same structure arises more than once through independent mutations *in the same generation*, each identical mutation is assigned the same innovation number.

- Every new node receives a globally new id. (I have no source for this. Maybe the problem is here)
- Equal fitness is assumed at the example below, so all genes are randomly inherited (on this case the probability is 100%, for demonstration purposes).

> In this case, equal fitnesses are assumed on the example below, so the disjoint and excess genes are also inherited randomly.

So we have two genomes after two generations, which suffered the exact same mutations at each generation: add_connection(0,2) at gen 1, add_node(1) at gen 2.

[image]

Even though the topology is exactly the same for both, the genomes don't share innovation numbers, so the crossover yields a more complex topology.
It seems to me that using global ids for nodes breaks the historical tracking of connections, which blows up the innovation counter pretty fast (around 1400 innovations in 100 gens for 100 individuals), and yields big, non-functional networks.

What am I missing?